# Format String as Date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, varchar

I have this stored Proc:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[GetWebinars]
(
    @GroupingCode varchar(max) = 'AVM',
    @ItemNumber varchar(max) out,
    @Title varchar(max) out,
    @SubTitle varchar(max) out,
    @ShortDescription varchar(max) out,
    @LongDescription varchar(max) out,
    @ShortImageUrl varchar(max) out,
    @MedImageUrl varchar(max) out,
    @LgImageUrl varchar(max) out,
    @GroupCode varchar(max) out,
    @StartDate varchar(max) out
)
AS
    select 
    @GroupingCode = prdtemp.groupingcode,
    @ItemNumber = prd.itemnumber,    
    @Title = t.brochuredesc,
    @SubTitle = prdtemp.SubTitle,
    @ShortDescription = prdtemp.shortdescription,
    @LongDescription = prdtemp.longdescription,
    @ShortImageUrl = prdtemp.SmallImagePath,
    @MedImageUrl  = prdtemp.MediumImagePath,
    @LgImageUrl = prdtemp.LargeImagePath,
    @GroupCode = prd.GroupCode,
    @StartDate = s.StartDate

    from pryor_producttemplate prdtemp
        inner join pryor_prdItmmst prd
        on prdtemp.groupingcode  = prd.groupcode
        inner join pryor_topics t
        on prd.itemnumber =  t.topiccode
        inner join Pryor_Schedule s
        on t.TopicCode = s.topiccode    

    where prdtemp.groupingcode=@GroupingCode and t.country = 'U.S.A'
```

My issue is @StartDate is a var char in the DB. How can I convert this to a proper date to render as D/M/YY?

Comment: Any idea of what's in column `StartDate`?  Something like "2/29/12" or "Christmas, 1899"?

Comment: what is `D/M/YY` format? how do you show `30-JAN-2012` in this format???

Comment: This is the crux of the question really, Are all of the "dates" in the startdate column of the same format??? ie were they strictly controlled when entering the values into the database?

Comment: If `StartDate` is stored as a `varchar` in the database, you have one issue. The fact that you want everything to be treated as strings (as evidenced by all the `varchar(max)` output parameters) is another. If you're going to treat the database as an expensive replacement for a CSV file, expect more problems in the future.

Comment: Ok. sorry for the typo. I want to display M/D/Y. @Laurence Burke all dates in the Db have this format: 2012-01-31. I need to render 01/31/2012. Damien The Unbeliever: This is not my table this is a clients table and yes it is incredibly messed up. But I am trying to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `convert` function to convert the string to a datetime:

```
@StartDate = convert(datetime, s.StartDate, 120)
```

The third parameter specifies the date format. The value 120 for example specifies the human friendly ISO 8601 format. See the reference for [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for all date formats supported.

Naturally you also have to change the type of the variable:

```
@StartDate datetime out
```

Comment: It's a reasonable assumption to make that they are in a convertible format when the OP hasn't clarified, and convert allows for the data to be in many different formats. They wouldn't all have to be in the same format, just in some standard date format.

Comment: @EB - you say you 'keep getting sql syntax errors'  What errors specifically?

Comment: Thanks Guffa. This worked. Anyway to lop off the time at the end and just get the date? Also in the convert statement, how could I format this as 02/21/2012? Right now it still renders as 2012-02-16 Thanks

Comment: @DaveE. My mistake. I deleted that comment. Syntax errors were my fault.

Comment: The third parameter in the CONVERT statement sets the style.  '120'=ODBC canonical (yyyy-mm-dd); try the US style '101' (mm/dd/yyyy).

Comment: @EB.: A datetime value doesn't have a format at all, so how it renders depends on where and how you convert it to a string. If you want to return it as a varchar from the procedure, you would convert it twice: `convert(varchar(max), convert(datetime, s.StartDate, 120), 101)`